# Terraform Ec2 creation denied irrespective of access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, tags, terraform-provider-aws

Reading the title you might be coming to a perspective that I do not have right access. But I do have admin access. So here is my sceneraio.

I have a Service control policy enabled that denies resource creation if specific tags are absent. So if I create a ec2 instance and a volume that does not have mandatory tag it denies creation with error `"UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation."`

This is working perfectly fine from console but when I use terraform for ec2 creation it is showing me the same error that I am not authorized even though I have added the tags.

This is my SCP that has been enabled.

```
{
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/owner": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my terraform script

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  alias = "virginia"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami = "ami-051f7e7f640dc1"
  count = "1"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
  key_name = "keypair"

  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-xyz", "sg-abc"]
  subnet_id              = "subnet-xyz"

  tags = {
    owner = "aws"
  }

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted             = true

    tags = {
      owner       = "aws"
    }

    volume_size = 8
    volume_type = "gp2"
  }
}
```

- I tried adding default tags in provider block
- I removed the SCP and deployed it is working
- I have admin access to the account

Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at cloudtrail for the api request and error

Comment: Does your TF work without the SCP?

Comment: Yes I did. But nothing useful I found from there. Here is my event record.

"errorCode": "Client.UnauthorizedOperation",  "errorMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message

Comment: Yes Marcin my tf works perfectly fine without SCP

Comment: @sahithpalika are there any tagging policies applied at the organization level? I also noticed you are using the aliased provider version, so you may try adding `provider = aws.virginia` to the resource blocks.

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes, the tag policy is applied on the organisation level.

Right now I tried adding provider as you suggested but did not work. I specifically do not need the alias, but maybe required in the future. For more info, I also tried removing the alias but no luck.

Comment: Well, does the code violate the tagging policy then?

Comment: If it works from the console and not locally, then you might not be using the right credentials/profile locally

Comment: @Marko Seems like that is the case. But I do not know why? I need the owner tag and I providing it. Everything is fine from the console, is it anything with terraform? 

As i previosuly mentioned I could create resources in absence of SCP and tags are being added to both root volume and instance.

Comment: Hi @Paolo, I am afraid that is not the case as my team has initally, generated new keys that has admin access.  I strongly believe that it is not something with keys, profile or access.

Comment: @sahithpalika If this is not the organization root/management account, the SCPs apply to **all** users, even the account root user.

Comment: @Marko I get it, I was highlighting admin access to just eliminate the thought process of I do not have adequate access. By the way, SCP is enabled in root account (AWS organisation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to deny the EC2 creation if necessary tags are not added while creating. But while trying to create EC2 through terraform, it is getting denied by your SCP policy because terraform first creates the instance, and then attempts to add the tags. This creates an issue for RequestTag because this requires the tags be added at resource creation and not after the resource creation as such is causing an access to be denied.

This points to the reason why you are able to perform exactly the same action using the console/ CloudFormation with no issue but Terraform is encountering issues.

At this point I would say that if you are looking to continue with automating this process I would recommend using CloudFormation as this issue has already been resolved on that service. Otherwise it may be required that you remove this condition from the SCP such that Terraform can perform this action.

References:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17412
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3484

Comment: Oh. This could be not possible from Terraform if this is the case. I guess I need to work around. Thank you.